# discord.js javascript command handler - cannot find module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been making a discord bot and I am following a tutorial to make a music bot, but to do so I need to make a command handler.

I've been using this video: https://youtube.com/watch?v=DjwwHG0AWsk to make the command handler, but received this error when running my code:

> cannot find module ‘./commands/${f}’

If anyone can help me, that would be great.
My code can be found here: https://hastebin.com/agusufiwar.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used wrong quotes for template strings
Use a backtick instead of singlequote and it should work

On like 22

```
var cmds = require('./commands/${f}');
```

Change to

```
var cmds = require(`./commands/${f}`);
```

Comment: That seems to have got past that error, but now it gives me the error of ```message.content.slice(...).split is not a function```. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: you have a typo again change `prefix.legnth` to prefix.length !

Comment: That's a real big facepalm moment there! Thanks for all the help. I'll check that now!

Comment: yeah, do consider upvote/ accept the answer if it helps solve the problem :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But I just saved it with all my lengths changed to the correct spelling and I am still getting the same error. Is there anything else I have messed up or missed spelt?

Comment: update the link., you had a typo with `split` as `spilt`

Comment: show latest code, and consider creating a new question too, since the original question has been solved now.

Comment: OK. I'll make a new question now. Thanks for the help!